# How to install Qtwebengine on Windows

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have made an apps on Linux and now I try to launch it on Windows.

I have installed Python 3.6 and pyqt5 (pip.exe install pyqt5 => PyQt5-5.11.2-5.11.1-cp35.cp36.cp37.cp38-none-win32.whl).

I have this error : ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets'

I am trying since a few hours to fix the problem but I do not find a solution.

It seems the module is in the pyqt installer from the website but this installer does not exist for python 3.6.

I am completely stuck now, anybody has an idea ?

Thank you.

Comment: https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5 *Note that for v5.11 and later the 32-bit Windows wheels do not contain the WebEngine modules.* the solution is to use 64-bit python

Comment: Thank you, I have solved the problem with python 64 bits :)

But If I want to build my application for Windows 32bits, I can't ?